# java BlockingQueue and JDBC batch update

Tags: java, jdbc, concurrency

I am looking for java concurrency solution, so that i can use JDBC Batch updates. 
BlockingQueue will let me one item at time, i have already have method on DAO to batch update, but I need some solution so that i can take advantage of JDBC Batch update instead of single record updates.

My worker thread looks following:

```
class DBWorker extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Pair<Long, Status> p = dbQ.take();
                    //--
                    orderDao.updateStatus(p.getLeft(), p.getRight());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is gather multiple `Pair` objects into a `Collection` and then pass that `Collection` off to the code that will perform the batch update.

You can try something like:

```
while (true) {
    Pair<Long, Status> p = dbQ.take();
    List<Pair> collectedPairs = new ArrayList();
    while (p!=null) {
        collectedPairs.add(p);
        p = dbQ.poll();
    }
    orderDao.batchUpdate(collectedPairs);
}
```

However the above code will mostly issue batches with generally small sizes. You can adapt that example though to use the timed polling method `BlockingQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit)` to introduce some latency and try to gather larger batch sizes.

Answer (score 2):

`BlockingQueue`'s have a nice method, `drainTo()` that basically takes all the entries and puts it in a collection. Although it is not blocking, so you're still going to need a `take()` before calling it so that it won't have a busy wait. Instead of updating one and one, you also need a method for updating the DB in batches. For instance:

```
ArrayList<Pair<Long, Status>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Long, Status>>();
list.add(dbQ.take());
//sleep(int n) - if you want to wait for more entries before submitting the batch - otherwise batches will probably be pretty small..
dbQ.drainTo(list);
orderDao.updateInBatch(list);
```

Comment: +1 For suggesting `drainTo`, I often forget about that nice method.